# Host multiple sites on IIS Windows EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, iis-8.5

I have an Amazon EC2 Windows Server 2012 instance set up with IIS 8.5 and I'm trying to setup multiple sites, each with a unique port binding. The problem comes when trying to access these sites from outside the instance.

Configuration:

- I have tried many different ports, including: 80, 81, 8080, 2468, 10000, 10001, 10002
- I have configured physical path authentication/authorization for the sites/app pools
- I have configured Windows Firewall to allow inbound access on the necessary ports
- I have configured the EC2 security groups to allow inbound access on the necessary ports

The only ports I have found to work are 80 and 10000. (Likely irrelevant, but the FTP site is working correctly.)

Troubleshooting:

- sites are accessible via localhost on the instance
- When I use an online port checker tool, the ports show as open
- "netstat -an" shows the ports as LISTENING
- browsers (Chrome, FF, IE) show connection timed out when attempting to browse to one of these sites
- cannot telnet into any port except 80 (not even 10000 which works in browser)
- disabling Windows firewall on any/all profiles doesn't help
- allowing all inbound traffic in EC2 security group doesn't help

I don't think this should be a complicated problem, but I've spent a long time trying to figure it out and find answers online, and I haven't come across anything relevant. Most of the search results say to open the ports in one firewall or another, which I've done to my knowledge.

Am I missing something? Other troubleshooting ideas? Let me know if I can provide more information. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried connecting from various networks? The data you provided points to your local network being the problem.

Comment: Not for nothing but why not use Host Headers instead of multiple ports?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I ended up going with Host Headers.

Answer (score 0):

I know my answer is quite late, but the only other item I can think of is that you EC2 instance is within a VPN subnet that has a Network ACL that's only allowing inbound on port 80.  Where security groups can control instance-specific in/out rules, the Network ACLs site around this and operate in the same way, but at an entire subnet level.